# How to Use Zend framework 2 to redirect a list of old URL to new controller/actions with 301 status

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a list of 301 redirect that i used to use on my .htaccess ( no zend framework 2 ) in the example below:

```
redirect 301 /boas-praticas-de-laboratorio /curso/boas-praticas-de-laboratorio

redirect 301 /autorizacoes-licencas-funcionamento /curso/autorizacao-de-funcionamento

redirect 301 /automacao-em-laboratorios /curso/automacao-em-laboratorios
```

but on my zend framework 2 application it doesn't works good.
How can i make a list of redirect 301 on zend framework 2?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't works good"? What exactly happens and what behavior would you expect?

Comment: It just doesn't redirects and tell me that don't found the controller

Comment: "...tell me that don't found the controller" - that's the real problem you should focus on. Redirection in .htaccess should work just fine, there should be no need to bring that into the app itself.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I fixed the Controller message, but in the page what i needed to go to the 301 redirect is comming the page: "A 404 ERROR OCCURRED PAGE NOT FOUND."